# How to linebreak long string constructs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am editing SQLite SQL statements of substantial length.

How can I break these into several lines to allow comfortablt editing?

```
const char *sql = "SELECT arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments FROM a, b, WHERE condition condition condition condition condition condition condition"
```

into

```
const char *sql = "SELECT arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments
                          arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments
                     FROM a, b
                    WHERE condition condition condition"
```

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const char *sql = "SELECT arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments"
                          "arguments arguments arguments arguments arguments"
                    "FROM a, b"
                    "WHERE condition condition condition";
```